# Android: execute a method and terminate it after a timeout

Tags: java, android, timeout

I need to execute a Java method for at most X seconds.
In case the method's code does not terminate after X seconds, I need my execution to continue.

I tried to use the following code (using the ExecutorService class).

```
private void execLoop(){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    int iteration;
    for(iteration=0;iteration<10;iteration++) {
        CallableTask ct = new CallableTask();
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(ct);
        try {
            future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class CallableTask implements Callable {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        Log.d("TIME","executed!");
        int t=0;
        boolean c = true;
        while(c){
            t+=0; // infinite loop: this method will never terminate
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I expect from this code is to print to logcat, every 5 seconds, the string "executed!" for 10 times.
However, the execution gets stuck in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, you never shut down your executor. Add the following line as the last statement in your `execLoop()` method:

```
executor.shutdownNow();
```

Then, since the shutdown is accomplished by interrupting your threads, you need to make sure that your `CallableTask` listens to interrupts. One way is to use `Thread.sleep()` instead of `t+=0`:

```
while(c){
    Thread.sleep(500); // This will be interrupted when you call shutdownNow()
}
```